# What does mean ' [ ! -f $2 ] in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I think [ ! -f $2 ] means

$2 file doesn't exist.

is it correct?

I'm pretty sure [ ! -f ] means
file doesn't exist. but I'm not sure for $2.

give me some help.

Comment: Did try searching for it? -> https://is.gd/wqaWn1

Answer (score 4):

`[` is `test`, and `man test` tells us:

> ```
>   -f FILE
>          FILE exists and is a regular file
> ```

so, well, your `$2` is the filename, the second parameter to the script you're in.